# How to remove the vertical asymptote using curve function in R

Tags: r, plot

```
curve(
    (x+3)/(x+2), 
    from = -9, 
    to   = 6,
    xlab = "",
    ylab = "",
#   xlim = ,
    ylim = c(-0.5,2.5),
    las  = 1,
    lwd  = 2
    )
```

[image]

How can I remove the vertical black line in this plot?
So I can add it myself using

```
abline(
v = -2,
h = 1,
lty = 2,
col = 2,
lwd = 2
)
```

**Update**
Is there a "global" option to modify this?
If I have to change this toleranace or draw it piecewise for every function I use, it would be tedious ....

Answer (score 2):

```
n <- 1e3
from <- -9
to <- 6

tol <- (to - from) / n

curve(
  ifelse(abs(x + 2) > tol, (x+3)/(x+2), NA), 
  from = from, 
  to   = to,
  n = n,
  xlab = "",
  ylab = "",
  #   xlim = ,
  ylim = c(-0.5,2.5),
  las  = 1,
  lwd  = 2
)
```

Comment: is there a global option to remove these asymptotes so I dont have to change it for every functions of this kind one by one?

Comment: There is no reliable way to detect such asymptotes numerically for arbitrary functions.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it does that is because the "continuous" domain of `x` hits the most-nonzero *finite* `y` (negative) that R recognizes and then starts again at the most nonzero *finite* `y` (positive) and continues the line through those two points. The answer to this is to stop the curve immediately before that point (`x = -2`) and draw a second line just after that point, adding `xlim=` to the first call and `add=TRUE` to the second. (Most of the options are not needed or even used when `add=TRUE`, so I'll omit them here for demonstration of "simple".)

```r
curve(
    (x+3)/(x+2), 
    from = -9, 
    to   = -2.1,
    xlab = "",
    ylab = "",
    xlim = c(-9, 6),
    ylim = c(-0.5,2.5),
    las  = 1,
    lwd  = 2
    )
curve(
    (x+3)/(x+2), 
    from = -1.9, 
    to   = 6,
    lwd  = 2,
    add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: is there a global option to remove these asymptotes so I dont have to draw every piece for every functions of this kind one by one?

Comment: not that I'm aware of